# How to add new tab and data in Wordpress Users section

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to add new tab and new data in wordpress users. Please see the image below.

[image: Screetshot]

The points tab came from the plugin `mycred` but i don't know what was used. What I think was it was done using:

```
$tabs = apply_filters( 'mycred_edit_profile_tabs', $tabs, $user, false );

do_action( 'mycred_edit_profile', $user, $type );
```

I want this code in my functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new tabs in this way:

```
    $tabs[] = array(
        'label'   => __( 'Profile', 'mycred' ),
        'url'     => 'some-url.php',
        # optionally some class for active tab
        'classes' => ( $current === NULL ) ? 'nav-tab nav-tab-active' : 'nav-tab'
    );
```

Comment: whats is this ? Just a variable assignment?!